# how to do facets on symfony2 : FOSElasticaBundle?

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

how to do a facet query with elasticsearch on symfony2 ?

i can do query, and got result, it works!

now on this query, i would like to facets the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  public function facetAction()
  {           
        // index
        $search = $this->get('fos_elastica.index.appellations.appellation');


        $query = new \Elastica\Query\MatchAll();

        $elasticaQuery = new \Elastica\Query();
        $elasticaQuery->setQuery($query);
        $elasticaQuery->setSize(550);

        $elasticaFacet = new \Elastica\Facet\Terms('regions');
        $elasticaFacet->setField('regions');
        $elasticaFacet->setSize(550);

        $elasticaFacet->setOrder('reverse_count');

        $elasticaQuery->addFacet($elasticaFacet);

        // ResultSet
        $elasticaResultSet = $search->search($elasticaQuery);

        // Get Facets
        $elasticaFacets = $elasticaResultSet->getFacets();

        foreach ($elasticaFacets['regions']['terms'] as $elasticaFacet) {

            $results[] = $elasticaFacet;
        }       

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse
        ('ApplicationGhvAppellationsBundle:Default:indexFacets.html.twig', array(
        'appellations' => $results
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Facets are going to be deprecated here is the updated code with aggregations

```
public function aggregationAction()
{           
    // index
    $search = $this->get('fos_elastica.index.appellations.appellation');


    $query = new \Elastica\Query\MatchAll();

    $elasticaQuery = new \Elastica\Query();
    $elasticaQuery->setQuery($query);
    $elasticaQuery->setSize(550);

    $elasticaAggreg= new \Elastica\Aggregation\Terms('regions');
    $elasticaAggreg->setField('regions');
    $elasticaAggreg->setSize(550);

    $elasticaAggreg->setOrder('_count', 'desc');

    $elasticaQuery->addAggregation($elasticaAggreg);

    // ResultSet
    $elasticaResultSet = $search->search($elasticaQuery);

    // Get Aggregations
    $elasticaAggregs = $elasticaResultSet->getAggregations();

    foreach ($elasticaAggregs['regions']['buckets'] as $elasticaAggreg) {

        $results[] = $elasticaAggreg;
    }       

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse
    ('ApplicationGhvAppellationsBundle:Default:indexFacets.html.twig', array(
    'appellations' => $results
    ));
}
```